# How to apply the output of python's difflib.unified_diff to the original string?

Tags: python, diff

So, using Python's [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html), I can generate a diff of two strings:

```
foo = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n Nullam sed orci lobortis lectus bibendum vehicula.\n Integer iaculis eros porttitor velit porttitor scelerisque.\n Nunc venenatis nibh.'.splitlines()
bar = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n Mauris placerat, odio ut viverra gravida, elit leo tincidunt nisi, a pellentesque velit arcu id magna.\n Integer iaculis eros porttitor velit porttitor scelerisque.\n Nunc venenatis nibh.'.splitlines()

diff = difflib.unified_diff(foo, bar, lineterm='')
```

We can then check out the diff if we so desired:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(diff)
--- 
+++ 
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
- Nullam sed orci lobortis lectus bibendum vehicula.
+ Mauris placerat, odio ut viverra gravida, elit leo tincidunt nisi, a pellentesque velit arcu id magna.
  Integer iaculis eros porttitor velit porttitor scelerisque.
  Nunc venenatis nibh.
```

And here's where I'm stuck. How can I apply that diff to string `foo` to result in string `bar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ndiff then you can restore the original string using restore

```
>>> diff = difflib.ndiff(foo, bar)
>>> diff = list(diff)
>>> print ''.join(difflib.restore(diff, 2))
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed orci lobortis lectus bibendum baculo mihi. Integer iaculis eros porttitor velit porttitor scelerisque. Nunc venenatis nibh.
>>> ''.join(difflib.restore(diff, 2))==''.join(bar)
True
>>> ''.join(difflib.restore(diff, 1))==''.join(foo)
True
>>>
```

Please note since unified diffs usually drops lines that compared equal to begin with it would be almost impossible to restore to the original string. ndiff shows everything, so it would be straight forward to restore the original.

Comment: By 'restore original' you mean generate bar (string 2) from foo+diff?

Comment: Yes In a way. What I mean is to restore bar from diff or foo from diff. Either of them is supported. If you pass `2` as an argument to `restore` it will restore bar for `1` it restores foo

Comment: Q: "How do I apply X". A: "Apply Y, then Z", Wat? ndiff is useless, it stores the entire file. The point of unified diff is that it only encodes the difference. GNU patch can take foo + diff and produce bar, so I have no idea why you say `it would be almost impossible to restore the original string`. Restoring the original string is the *entire reason* diff tools exist.